# Получить ip адрес пользователя используя Docker

Tags: php, yii2, docker, docker-compose

Всем привет.
Не могу получить ip адрес пользователя на сайте. Все время выдает адрес докер-контейнера.
Получаю в php с помощью `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Собственно вопрос, как настроить докер так, чтобы я смог получать ip адрес пользователей.

Вот мои конфиги:

Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  
    nginx:
        build:
            context: docker/nginx
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:/var/www
        ports:
            - 83:83
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
...
```

nginx

```
server {
    listen 83;
    index index.php;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;
    root /var/www/backend/web;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php

Comment: Вопрос как раз таки в этом и состоит. Как настроить сервер, чтобы $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] выдавал реальный ip пользователя

Comment: Ваш сервер работает правильно, как должен работать. Зачем пытаться настроить его не верно ?  Вы должны в приложении забирать нужные вам данные из нужного заголовка.

Comment: из какого заголовка? Как получить ip пользователя тогда?

Comment: Вот как бы намекает - 
`proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;`

Проставляется заголовок куда проставляется удаленный адрес. Данный заголовок вы должны видеть в $_SERVER. Я тут не уверен что он проставляется в вашем location, по идее должен, ежели нет, то добавьте.